# Routing WCF Data Services

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, service

I could able to route the calls to WCF SOAP services using Routing Services in .NET 4.0
In the same way I need to route the request to WCF Data Services calls from one server to other server. Is it possible to achieve it using ASP.NET Routing module?

Comment: Can you please clarify, I´m not sure what you are intending to use: the .Net 4 WCF Routing Service (System.ServiceModel.Routing) or the Asp.net Routing used for MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With REST based services, you're relying on "raw" HTTP as your transport. A simple "router" could accomplish this by performing these steps:

- Capture the HTTP request
- Determine the target service and "redirect" the HTTP request to it
- Capture the HTTP response
- Transmit the contents of the response to the client

The ASP.NET Routing module could be made to work this way but it wasn't intended for that.